# Вывод полученного из БД изображения

Tags: python, sqlite, opencv

Необходимо хранить в БД эталонные изображения для последующего сравнения образца с ними при помощи OpenCV. Для записи в БД изображение бинаризируется. И при его извлечении мне необходимо вернуть его обратно в формат подходящий для дальнейшей обработки средствами OpenCV.

```
import sys, cv2 as cv, sqlite3
img = cv.imread(sys.argv[1], 1)
connection=sqlite3.connect("imgdb.db")
cursor=connection.cursor()
sql = 'CREATE TABLE Images (iD INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, img BLOB)'
cursor.execute(sql)
name = input('name: ')
bin = buffer(img)
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO Images VALUES (NULL,?,?)', (name, bin))
cursor.execute("SELECT img FROM Images LIMIT 1")
img = cursor.fetchone()[0]
cv.imshow("name", img)
connection.commit()
connection.close()
cv.waitKey()
```

На 12 строке программа вываливается, ругаясь на неподходящий тип: `TypeError: mat is not a numpy array, neither a scalar`. Подскажите как решить проблему. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`buffer(img)` содержит данные из `img` `numpy` массива без размеров и типа. Чтобы сохранить и размер (shape) и тип (dtype), можно использовать `pickle`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pickle
import sqlite3
import sys
import cv2 # $ sudo apt-get install python-opencv

filename = sys.argv[1] # image path
img = cv2.imread(filename)
db = sqlite3.connect(':memory:') # use in-memory database for the demo

# create table
db.execute('CREATE TABLE Images (name TEXT, img BLOB)')
# put image into db
blob = pickle.dumps(img, -1)
db.execute('INSERT INTO Images VALUES (?,?)', (filename, sqlite3.Binary(blob)))

# get image from db
blob = db.execute("SELECT img FROM Images LIMIT 1").fetchone()[0]
img = pickle.loads(blob)

# display image until any key is pressed
cv2.imshow('image', img)
print('Press any key..')
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Это работает, но не ясно зачем сохранять изображение как `numpy` массив. Гораздо более экономично сохранить jpeg данные напрямую или даже только само имя файла с изображением.

Стоит заметить, что запись и чтение небольших изображений (таких как thumbnails), используя sqlite, может быть даже быстрее (35%) и занимать меньше места (20%), чем работа с файлами напрямую с диска: [35% Faster Than The Filesystem](https://www.sqlite.org/fasterthanfs.html)

Comment: Да, хранить изображение как `numpy` массив совершенно незачем, это я переборщил. Я преследую две цели:
1. Хранить данные в единственном экземпляре.
2. Использовать как можно меньше сущностей-ключей для получения изображения.
Для этого в стороннем приложении макросом формируем изображение и записываем его в БД без сохранения на диск. Но вариант с использованием в качестве ключа путь к файлу не пришел в голову, а так он решает заодно и проблему размещения БД. Спасибо за решение проблемы и еще большее спасибо за идею.

Answer (score 1):

Если проводить аналогию с OpenCV C++ API (OpenCV Python API является скорее всего обёрткой над первым), то решение заносить объект класса матрицы в отдельный в памяти буфер будет некорректным. Класс матрицы непосредственно не содержит самих данных изображения, но оперирует указателями на массив. Соответственно можно предположить, что строка:

```
bin = buffer(img)
```

не сохраняет информацию о пикселях, а лишь указатель на динамически выделенную область в памяти, что естественным образом впоследствии оказывается бесполезным.

В C++ API (вероятно, аналогично и в Python) доступ к одномерному массиву (буферу) данных осуществляется через публичное поле `data`:

```
uchar *elems = my_matrix.data;
```

Необходимо отметить, что полученный таким образом указатель `elems` имеет тип `unsigned char` и в изображении, имеющем два и более цветовых каналов, рассматриваемый массив байт не соответствует массиву пикселей. Это так называемые raw-данные, которые, тем не менее, очень удобно сохранять в какое-нибудь хранилище, типа таблицы в БД. Наверняка функция `buffer()` теперь отработает корректно.

Размер массива `elems` можно получить, воспользовавшись формулой:

```
size_t elems_length = my_matrix.total() * my_matrix.elemSize();
```

Метод `total()` возвращает общее количество пикселей в изображении, а `elemSize()` - количество байт на пиксель с учётом цветовых каналов.

Однако полученный массив данных без так называемой заголовочной информации об изображении, как то размер (ширина и высота в пикселях), количество цветовых каналов, а также тип данных (`uchar`, `int`, `float` или `double`), впоследствии не позволит корректно восстановить матрицу из БД. Заголовочную информацию необходимо также сохранять.

При чтении данных изображения из файла функцией `imread()`, последняя по умолчанию (или если указан флаг `IMREAD_COLOR`) создаёт трёхканальную матрицу с типом данных `uchar`, то есть `CV_8UC3`. Это будет соответствовать формату `BGR24`. Если указать загрузку изображения в оттенках серого (флаг `IMREAD_GRAYSCALE`), то результатом уже будет тип данных `CV_8UC1` (синоним `CV_8U`) и соответственно формат - `Grayscale`.

Каким образом и в каком виде следует сохранять обозначенную метаинформацию в таблицу БД - это выбор автора кода. Кто-то предпочитает создавать отдельные колонки, в которых метаданные будут храниться отдельно, а кто-то объединяет массив пикселей и метаданные в свою собственную произвольную структуру, из которой, по его мнению, будет проще восстановить исходное изображение. Если OpenCV используется совместно с каким-нибудь фреймворком общего назначения, например, Qt, то всё может свестись к копированию данных в `QByteArray`, а последний нехитрым образом будет перенесён в БД.

Восстановление матрицы из таблицы БД должно заключаться в получении массива данных и метаинформации раздельно. После чего производится вызов конструктора класса `Mat` (С++):

```
Mat my_matrix(rows, cols, type, data);
```

где:

- `rows` - кол-во строк;
- `cols` - кол-во колонок;
- `type` - тип данных, например `CV_8UC3`;
- `data` - указатель на массив данных.

Для Python, очевидно, код будет отличаться, однако общий ход действий тот же.

Comment: `buffer(img)` приводит к сохранению всех пиксельных данных (без мета-данных: размера массива и конкретного dtype). Например, если 100x100 картинка, 3 цвета по 32-бит на цвет, то `buffer(img)` приведёт к сохранению `100*100*3*4` байт.

Comment: @jfs , раз `buffer()` в Python так функционирует, то тогда в Вашем случае не хватает только сохранения метаданных. Вы искали какой-то универсальный метод, что сохранит в БД и то, и то?

Comment: Я ничего не искал, просто указал что заявление об указателях в Вашем ответе неточно: `buffer(img)` приводит к сохранению самих пиксельных данных, а не только указателей на них

Comment: @jfs , это было не заявление, но предположение.