# Как спрятать файл в sqlite: как записать двоичные данные в БД

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite3

Пишу бота на Python с использованием sqlite. Хочу прятать разные вещи в базе данных. БД поддерживает хранение изображений в ячейках типа BLOB. Как туда кинуть например *.pdf файл и как его потом оттуда достать.

Используется Питон 3.5

Comment: 0_o )))  Какие еще заголовки? И где прописывает? Хотите хранить большой текст - перед помещением в БД сожмите его по алгоритму LZMA, или PPMd, и записывайте результирующие бинарные данные в BLOB. Не пойму суть вопроса.

Comment: БД ничего никуда не "прописывает". Что ей дали - то и хранит, то и возвращает. Никакой инициативы без приказа. Если же возвращается не то, что отдавали на хранение - либо неправильно просите, либо проявляет ненужную инициативу (или содержит ошибки) средство, которое получает/отображает.

Comment: Речь идёт о заголовках файлов, о их дескрипторах. BLOB это байт-код, засунуть туда можно что угодно. С помощью DB Browser for Sqlite, в тестовых целях, залил в базу данных текстовый файл, но при его выгрузке, он дописал заголовок файла (дескриптор) второй раз и текст стал нечитаемым. А я могу захотеть добавить в бд файлы *.xlsx или *.docx. Меня интересует, как с помощью Python, сохранить файл в бд, и как его оттуда вытащить корректно

Comment: Что такое, в вашем понимании, "дескриптор файла"?

Comment: @PavelMayorov http://open-file.ru/articles/file-header но я не об этом. Мне нужно, файл в побайтово в таблицу записать и побайтово оттуда извлечь. Без искажений. Скорее всего, тема дескрипторов связана с DB Browser for Sqlite, а не с самим sqlite. В любом случае не знаю как с помощью питона записать побайтово файл в таблицу

Comment: Учтите, что правильно это называется не "заголовок" и не "дескриптор", а "сигнатура".

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Вывод полученного из БД изображения](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/457596/23044)

Comment: @jfs спасибо конечно же, но ответ я уже нашёл. От использования самой технологии хранения отказался. Ибо смысл грузить лишний раз БД? Вопрос удалять не стал, вдруг кому пригодится

Comment: @svmitin: ссылка не только для вас. Цель сайта аккумулировать вопросы/ответы, возникающие у программистов. Чтобы каждый раз, каждому программисту не приходилось один и тот же вопрос с нуля решать. То есть цель не столько вам лично помочь, а так чтобы будущие посетители из веб-поисковика пользу получили. [Какими должны быть критерии оценки качества базы знаний?](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/4181/23044)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import sqlite3 as lite  
import sys  

con = lite.connect("test.db")  
cur = con.cursor()  

#Загрузка файла в БД  
file_input = open("blank.pdf", "rb")  
file = file_input.read()  
file_input.close()  
binary = lite.Binary(file)  
cur.execute("INSERT INTO files(file) VALUES (?)", (binary,) )  
con.commit()  

#Выгрузка файла из БД  
cur.execute("SELECT file FROM files LIMIT 1")  
data = cur.fetchone()[0]  
file_output = open("blank2.pdf","wb")  
file_output.write(data)  
file_output.close()  
con.close()
```

Comment: не стоит `import sqlite3 as lite` использовать—это ухудшает читаемость кода без причины.